# How to handle simple error in Kotlin function Android

Tags: kotlin, error-handling, revenuecat

I'm having trouble handling error in the following function. I'm basically new to Kotlin. Here's my RevenueCat Login Code and I want to handle ::error in this code:

```
Purchases.sharedInstance.logInWith(
                    myUserID,
                    ::error // <- How to handle this? I want to retrieve error Code and Error Message.
            )
{ customerInfo, created  ->

// Handle Successful login here

}
```

Here's the code behind the function (within RevenueCat SDK)

```
@Suppress("unused")
fun Purchases.logInWith(
    appUserID: String,
    onError: (error: PurchasesError) -> Unit = ON_ERROR_STUB,
    onSuccess: (customerInfo: CustomerInfo, created: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    logIn(appUserID, logInSuccessListener(onSuccess, onError))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
Purchases.sharedInstance.logInWith(
     myUserID, 
 onError = { error -> 
        
        // Handle error here 
        
        }
```

Comment: Yes, this can be another solution.

Answer (score 2):

The double colon in `::error` is a [**function reference**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#function-references). It is basically a reference to the function `error()`.

And from your `logInWith()` function, we have `onError: (error: PurchasesError) -> Unit = ON_ERROR_STUB`, meaning that the function should take `PurchasesError` as input parameter and does not need to return.

So we can derive a function as the following:

```kotlin
fun error(error: PurchasesError) {
    // And you can do something with the error here
}
```